# How to allow User to click on next button from header section?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a list of buttons from which I navigate to other pages and display

Create a variable

```js
currentStep :number=1;
```

Add ng-disable for current step based on the button.

```html
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="first()" ng-disabled="currentStep == 1">First</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="second()" ng-disabled="currentStep == 2">Second</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger" (click)="third()" ng-disabled="currentStep == 3">Third</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-warning" (click)="fourth()" ng-disabled="currentStep == 4">Fourth</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="fifth()" ng-disabled="currentStep == 5">Fifth</button>
```

Won't to fill the data and allow the disabled button to passon second page

Comment: is it a form that you want to fill step to step?

Comment: is routing working fine?

Comment: yes routing working fine,just want to fill the form by step to step

Comment: you can keep a variable or a class to keep the State (something like "First Step", "Second State"  ...) and you share this State along components (using something like Observers) so any component can change the State and for example your links could be enable/disable according to that State. read about State Pattern for more ...

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable

```js
currentStep :number=1;
```

Add ng-disable for current step based on the button.

```html
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="first()" ng-disabled="currentStep == 1">First</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="second()" ng-disabled="currentStep == 2">Second</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger" (click)="third()" ng-disabled="currentStep == 3">Third</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-warning" (click)="fourth()" ng-disabled="currentStep == 4">Fourth</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="fifth()" ng-disabled="currentStep == 5">Fifth</button>
```